# JavaScript math function not working and returning Nan

Tags: javascript, function, math, nan

I have created a math function that is not working. When I call the function from another function it returns NaN, instead of a number.

The code block within the 'calculate' function works fine on it's own outside a function when I declare the variables, but these should be added as parameters when I call it as a function.

Can anyone tell me why the 'calculate' function isn't working?

```
function gatherInfo() {
    var clientAge = document.getElementById('clientAge').value;
    var propertyValue = document.getElementById('propertyValue').value;
    var OSmortgage = document.getElementById('OSmortgage').value;
    calculate(clientAge, propertyValue, OSmortgage);
}

var subButton = document.getElementById('subButton');
subButton.addEventListener('click', gatherInfo, false);


function calculate(clientAge, propertyValue, OSmortgage) {
    var ageArray = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 55; i < 96; i++) {
        ageArray.push(i);
    }
    var percentArray = [25.6, 26.6, 27.6, 28.6, 29.6, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.2, 44.4, 45.6, 46.8, 48, 49.2, 50.4, 51, 51.5, 52, 52.5, 53, 53.5, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55];

    var ageIndex = ageArray.indexOf(clientAge);
    var percentage = percentArray[ageIndex];
    var amount = ((propertyValue - OSmortgage) / 100) * percentage;
    result(amount, clientAge);
}


function result(amount, clientAge) {

    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    if (clientAge < 55) {
        result.textContent = 'You do not qualify for equity release.';
    } else {
        result.textContent = 'You could release £' + amount + ' of your property\'s value.';
    }
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Equity Release Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Equity Release Calculator</h1>

    <form id="form" method="get">

        <p>Age
        <input type="number" id="clientAge" required="required"> 
        </p>

        <p>Property value
        <input type="number" id="propertyValue" required="required">    
        </p>       

        <p>Outstanding mortgage amount
        <input type="number" id="OSmortgage" required="required">    
        </p>

        <p>Submit
        <input type="button" id="subButton" value="Get my quote">    
        </p>       

    </form>


    <p id="result"></p>

</body>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
</html>
```

Comment: Your functions operate on **local** variables and they do not return any values.

Comment: Cheers, I've passed the values/variables on into the next function through parameters.

Comment: Well one probable issue is that the `.value` properties of elements always give you *strings*, not numbers, and that can cause problems.

Comment: So your `ageArray` contains numbers, and therefore `.indexOf()` will never find the "clientAge" value you get from the DOM element.  Thus `ageIndex` will always be `-1`, `percentage` will be `undefined`, and `amount` will be `NaN`.

Comment: that could explain it, cheers i'll have a go at converting the strings to numbers

Comment: `var clientAge = +document.getElementById('clientAge').value;` — that added `+` is all you need. Of course if the string in the field is not a number you'll get `NaN` from that too but I assume that's obvious.

Comment: someone can please specify reason for down voting my answer

Comment: Cheers, this fix has worked, just adding the + symbol has turned the annoying string into a number value, the calculator now works! You're a legend!

Answer (score 0):

When you've put the code inside the calculate function it changes the scope of these variables local to the calculate function itself meaning you cannot access them outside of the function.

You'll need to add a 'return' to this function to access the output.

e.g.

```
function calculate(clientAge, propertyValue, OSmortgage) {
    var ageArray = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 55; i < 96; i++) {
        ageArray.push(i);
    }
    var percentArray = [25.6, 26.6, 27.6, 28.6, 29.6, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.2, 44.4, 45.6, 46.8, 48, 49.2, 50.4, 51, 51.5, 52, 52.5, 53, 53.5, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55];

    var ageIndex = ageArray.indexOf(clientAge);
    var percentage = percentArray[ageIndex];
    var amount = ((propertyValue - OSmortgage) / 100) * percentage;

    return amount;
}
```

Comment: [Because the OP edited the original question,] This answer doesn't seem like it is the problem, because `result()` modifies the DOM. The values are never actually used in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

problem was parsing, i have corrected your code so please check it and let me know. hope it will work for you :)

> var ageIndex = ageArray.indexOf(parseFloat(clientAge));
>       var percentage = percentArray[parseFloat(ageIndex)];
>       var amount = ((parseFloat(propertyValue) - parseFloat(OSmortgage)) / 100) * parseFloat(percentage);

```js
function gatherInfo() {
debugger
    var clientAge = document.getElementById('clientAge').value;
    var propertyValue = document.getElementById('propertyValue').value;
    var OSmortgage = document.getElementById('OSmortgage').value;
    calculate(clientAge, propertyValue, OSmortgage);
}

var subButton = document.getElementById('subButton');
subButton.addEventListener('click', gatherInfo, false);


function calculate(clientAge, propertyValue, OSmortgage) {
    var ageArray = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 55; i < 96; i++) {
        ageArray.push(i);
    }
    var percentArray = [25.6, 26.6, 27.6, 28.6, 29.6, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.2, 44.4, 45.6, 46.8, 48, 49.2, 50.4, 51, 51.5, 52, 52.5, 53, 53.5, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55];

    var ageIndex = ageArray.indexOf(parseFloat(clientAge));
    var percentage = percentArray[parseFloat(ageIndex)];
    var amount = ((parseFloat(propertyValue) - parseFloat(OSmortgage)) / 100) * parseFloat(percentage);
    alert("amount " + amount);
}


function result(amount, clientAge) {

    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    if (clientAge < 55) {
        result.textContent = 'You do not qualify for equity release.';
    } else {
        result.textContent = 'You could release £' + amount + ' of your property\'s value.';
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Equity Release Calculator</h1>

    <form id="form" method="get">

        <p>Age
        <input type="number" id="clientAge" required="required"> 
        </p>

        <p>Property value
        <input type="number" id="propertyValue" required="required">    
        </p>       

        <p>Outstanding mortgage amount
        <input type="number" id="OSmortgage" required="required">    
        </p>

        <p>Submit
        <input type="button" id="subButton" value="Get my quote">    
        </p>       

    </form>


    <p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: please specify reason for down voting so i could correct my mistakes and make ans more specific.

Comment: Cheers Dhaval, I managed to fix it by adding a + before document.getelementbyid... the .value was pulling the entry in as a string instead of a number

Comment: means my answer wasn't your solution right ? then you can undo accepting my answer :)

Comment: Oh sorry, this is my first time on here :)

Comment: no problem. you should always accept only that answer which helped you or solved your problem so it can guild others as well

Answer (score 0):

Use parseint or parsefloat for all the variable:

```
var ageIndex = ageArray.indexOf(parseFloat(clientAge)); 
var percentage = percentArray[parseFloat(ageIndex)]; 
var amount = ((parseFloat(propertyValue) - parseFloat(OSmortgage)) / 100) * parseFloat(percentage);
```